# Designer learning Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I already started learning online but everything out there seems oriented to developers not designers with no baggage.

I'm a graphic designer and I'm coding recently and I am very decided to master RoR.

Thanks for the nudge!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm also interested in learning Ruby on Rails. I haven't yet started - I've preferred to put it on hold until I have a little more experience with css and html. Actually I think I'll learn javascript too, before diving into ruby on rails.

But anyway... while I was on the search for the best way to learn ruby on rails, Michael Hart's tutorial or guide (whatever) came up very often as the best resource for the beginning programmer. Here's the link if you're interested > http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ .

I remember an article, too, by net tuts, which suggested a path for learning ruby... I'll go see if I can still find it...

...

Yup! Here it is > http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ruby/the-best-way-to-learn-ruby-on-rails/

Hope this helps a little!

Answer (score 0):

[Code academy](http://codeacademy.org/programs#development), they are supposed to be top notch and don't require any kind of development background.

Answer (score 0):

If you're the visual type you might enjoy [Why's Poignant Guide](http://mislav.uniqpath.com/poignant-guide/) as an introduction to Ruby. Then perhaps [Agile Web Development with Rails](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1934356549). A working knowledge of HTML, CSS, and Javascript are also a must.

Comment: In Agile book, chap 7 Validation & Unit Testing, i feel, as the boring chapter in that book. Not articulated properly

Answer (score 0):

Always start by learning Ruby, not Rails. Starting with Rails leaves you with little understanding of what's going on, and all you can do is write a basic app and depend on libraries to supply functionality. You'll have a hard time doing something for which there isn't already a gem - at least, not while keeping your codebase clean and maintainable.

My colleague has written an excellent post on getting started with Ruby: http://www.jasimabasheer.com/posts/meta_introduction_to_ruby.html